# Send JSON data with render_template() in Flask

Tags: flask

I need some clarification.

1. I want to load a JSON file in a route and return it's data with the **render_template** function. I am new to working with JSON in Flask and wanted to know if this is possible?

   ```
    @app.route("/")
    def hello_world():

        script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #<-- 1.  # Access and open JSON file.
        rel_path = "roles.json"
        abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

        with open(abs_file_path) as f:
            data = json.load(f)

    return render_template('page.html', data=data) <----2. Want to send the JSON data with the template.
   ```
2. Then I want to then use this JSON data javascript inside the page.html Can this be done? Is there a better way?
3. The tutorials I have seen have had JSON data retrieved by a fetch request on page load or sent by creating a separate rout and returning just the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the "with" keyword wrong,

The `data` variable is only known in the "with" scope,

try this :

```
@app.route("/")
 def hello_world():

     script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
     rel_path = "roles.json"
     abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

     currentFile = open(abs_file_path)
     data = json.load(currentFile)
     currentFile.close()
 return render_template('page.html', data=data)
```